# ctime of a file in HDFS

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

Is there any way to get ctime of a file in HDFS? There's modification time in FileStatus but as files gets appended this time gets modified too.

Answer (score 0):

HDFS stores only the modified time and access time of the files as per the code [HERE](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-hdfs-project/hadoop-hdfs/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hdfs/server/namenode/INodeAttributes.java#L61-L65).

The modified time for files is the time when the file was last closed (such as when originally written and closed, or when reopened for append and closed).

During most of the time the modified time does not change for most files we place on HDFS unless they undergo any modifications as stated above. Hence, the modified can be referred as an acceptable creation time most of the time (NOT ALWAYS).